# GAE Java modules in development without constant reinstalling

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, ear

I cloned https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java and was able to run the development server after running mvn install, but having to run mvn install whenever I make a change and restart the development server would seriously slow down the work. Is there a way to configure the EAR use the modules' target directories instead of the WARs so that mvn appengine:devserver from the EAR directory would compile and use the most recent sources of the modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it, but you should provide us with some more information I suppose

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, no.  You can do "on the spot" debugging with Python, but Java will force you to recompile, therefore restart, everytime.

sorry :(. I know it's not ideal, but it's the way it is :(

You don't have to run "mvn clean install" every time, as it only takes care of your dependencies, something you only need to change if you import something new. You'll still need to run "mvn appengine:devserver" every time though

Comment: Thanks. I know about having to re-run devserver, my question was specific to modules - in the example project there was no single command to package the modules and run devserver. I ended up attaching the devserver goal in the EAR to a lifecycle phase after package (for example integration-test) so that running mvn integration-test from the parent packages all the WARs, the EAR and then runs devserver of the EAR.